# MySQL Join / Union / Distinct issue

Tags: mysql

Say i have 2 columns with emails, in an old system, witch is set up in a very bad way, anyhow

1 Table named Information, contains a field called value, and i only want the value is the key is "email", the other table called Email_queue contains a field called "email" which contains an email.

Now, i want to somehow join Information.value where type = email and Email_queue.email, and then sort it so i am left with unique emails from both tables.

This is what i have arrived at, i am not sure if it works, since the table contains a lot of emails.

```
SELECT DISTINCT value
FROM 
    (SELECT Information.value FROM Information
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
   Email_queue ON Information.id=Email_queue.id WHERE Information.key = 'email') t
```

Does this look correct?

Comment: are using mysql or sql server?

Comment: MySQL i removed the other tag

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just UNIONing 2 queries together. UNION by default will remove the duplicates:-

```
SELECT value AS email
FROM Information
WHERE key = 'email'
UNION
SELECT email
FROM Email_queue
```